# Проблема лимита data()

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.

Как увеличить лимит?

```
$("div#" + n).data({
    "size": json.result[i].size,
    "distribute": json.result[i].distribute,
    "torrent": json.result[i].torrent,
    "magnet": json.result[i].magnet,
    "url": json.result[i].url
});
```

Записывается только примерно 10 записей, потом пишет, что undefined.

Comment: В документации ничего не сказано о ограничении. Да и это абсурд - 10 записей.

Comment: Ну незнаю что тогда, но тогда подскажите что может вызвать что пишет undefiend? Просто листаю и все хорошо а потом в одном undefiened и все следующие также.

Answer (score 1):

Значит у элемента нет такого свойства, которое вы запрашиваете, возможно дело в переменной n, которая как я понял генерирует внутри цикла id элементов, при чем так, что первые 10( или примерно 10 ) id существуют, а остальные генерируются неверно .., попробуйте ( если это в вашем случае допустимо ) вместо обращения к id обратится к классу или как-то иначе... Проверьте ( alert ( n ) ) еще, если мое предположение верно, в кажой итерации переменную n если от нее нельзя отказаться.

Answer (score 0):

Если бы Вы посмотрели в документации, что означает undefined, то сразу можно было бы локализовать проблему. Наверняка же ошибка undefined возникает над каким-то элементом. И я больше чем уверен, что этим элементом является json.result.
На 99% гарантирую, что в возвращаемом json нет того элемента, который Вы пытаетесь считать. Покажите больше кода и, желательно, кусок json'а.